# Status of the Push Notification from google server

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Is there any Possible way for getting the status of the push notificatioin wheater it is queued for sending or already Send.
I had posted some push notifications to gcm server but customers didnt got it.
Is there any possible way for getting the status of the notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the status of an individual message from GCM server.

The response you get from Google only tells you whether your message was valid and accepted by GCM server.

Once the message reaches your app, the only way for your server to know about it is if your app notifies the server as part of handling the message.  That's something you'll have to implement yourself,  with an API call to your server.

Other then that, if a message was accepted by GCM server and didn't reach the app, you have no way of knowing whether Google attempted to deliver it or not.